# How to run Svelte in dev mode

Tags: svelte

I'm trying to get Svelte DevTools working and I believe it's not because I may not be in dev mode. When I first began my project two years back, there was the line `dev: !production,` in rollup.config.js:

```
 replace({ 'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify( 'development' ), preventAssignment: true}),
    css({ output: 'bundle.css' }),
    svelte({
      // enable run-time checks when not in production
      dev: !production,
      // we'll extract any component CSS out into
      // a separate file - better for performance
      emitCss: true
    }),
```

But after updating Svelte to a more recent version (currently 3.53.1), I received an error that the svelte plugin didn't recognize the "dev" property, so I had to comment it out to get it to compile. I'm thinking now that that's why I can't get Svelte Devtools to work.

**How does one enable Svelte dev mode in the current version of Svelte?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably in the `compilerOptions` now:

```js
svelte({
  //...
  compilerOptions: { dev: !production }
})
```

Type defined [here](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/blob/967e9f51ff649f776fa034db8aba23a5a1546294/src/compiler/interfaces.ts#L161).